# Laravel Global Variable Only In User Prefix

Tags: php, laravel

i try to make global variable in `app/providers/AppServiceProvider.php`.
i want to return the userID when prefix is webiste/user, i try to dump but the result is null

```
use Auth;
public function boot()
{
  dump(@Auth::guard('users')->user()->id); //Null
}
```

Comment: The authentication guard is not actually initialized until the `AuthServiceProvider` is ran which runs after `AppServiceProvider`. Any rate service provider is the wrong place for any auth related logic. All auth related logic should be in middleware or logic which is ran as part of the controller handling a request. This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have access to the auth user inside the boot method of AppServiceProvider this method is called before the authentication mechanism.

What you can do is you can create a ViewComposer and pass variables to any views you want.

First create a ServiceProvider lets say `ComposerServiceProvider` , you can use `php artisan make:provider ComposerServiceProvider` to generate one.
*dont forget to register the provider on your config/app.php file and use the below code

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory as ViewFactory;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(ViewFactory $view)
    {
        $view->composer('*', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\GlobalComposer');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Then create a GlobalComposer.php class file with below code

```
namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;

class GlobalComposer
{
    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
       $view->with('user', Auth::user());
    }
}
```

Now the asterisk on the boot method of the service provider means "all views" meaning for all the views of the project the GlobalComposer will take action. You can replace the asterisk with whatever view you want, you can use an array of views also e.g. `['auth/login', 'auth/register']`

Next on the GlobalComposer file inside the compose method you "compose" variables that you want to be passed on the views the Composer is binded to.

Check the Laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#view-composers) also

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments i guess that your problem can be solved simple by adding an authenticated new route in your `api.php` file.

Try this approach:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/webiste/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user()->id;
});
```

Comment: Thankyou, but thats not what i wanted to ask

Comment: I thought the problem was that you were not getting the id. So what you are trying to achieve is that when the logged in user visits:

/website/user    

logged in users id will appear? Cause that sounds like a routing fix and not a service